# how to calculate growth percentage using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to calculate the the percentage change from one quarter to another quarter. I am not able to figure out one issue here is my query

```
SELECT YearKey,
sum(Q1)Q1, sum(Q2)Q2, sum(Q3)Q3, sum(Q4)Q4
FROM myTable
group by YearKey
```

The result of this query would look like this:
[image]

But I want to add a new row for %change and total column at the end and here is the output I would like to see
[image]

Comment: This should be done in the application layer.  The columns have different types.  Although you could force them to conform, that is strong evidence that SQL is not the right tool for this job.

Comment: Are you sure about the math used to generate the %Change values shown? The Q1, Q2 and Q3 changes look positive from 2015 to 2016 and negative for Q4. The displayed %Change values have the opposite + / - signs.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the equation needed to compute for the percentage growth is

GDP = (GDPn - GDPo) / GDPo

This will yield a decimal growth rate. Multiply it with 100 to get percentage.

Just incorporate it in the SQL Query Statement.

```
SELECT 
  YearKey,
  Q1 = sum(Q1),
  Q2 = sum(Q2),
  Q2Q1percentage = ((sum(Q2) - sum(Q1)) / sum(Q1))*100,
  Q3 = sum(Q3),
  Q3Q2percentage = ((sum(Q3) - sum(Q2)) / sum(Q2))*100,
  Q4 = sum(Q4),
  Q4Q3percentage = ((sum(Q4) - sum(Q3)) / sum(Q3))*100
FROM 
  myTable
GROUP BY YearKey
```

Comment: Please leave an explanation of your code so others can learn and understand. Thanks!